# How do I pass date info to the MyDate class for dateHired?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the Employee class to send `day`, `month`, `year` to the MyDate class. The MyDate class receives the 3 variables and produces a toString() method to be used by the Employee class. My code so far:

**Employee class**

```
package lab3;

public class Employee extends Person {

    String office;
    double salary;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    MyDate dateHired;
    
    public Employee(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.office = "No office";
        this.salary = 1200.00;
        this.day = 1;
        this.month = 1;
        this.year = 1970;
    }
    
    public Employee(String name, String address, String phoneNumber, String email, String office, double salary, int day, int month, int year) {
        super(name, address, phoneNumber, email);
        this.office = office;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }
    
    public String getOffice() {
        return office;
    }
    
    public void setOffice(String office) {
        this.office = office;
    }
    
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\n" + "Office: " + getOffice()
        + "\n" + "Salary: " + getSalary() + "\n" + "Date Hired: " + dateHired.toString();
    }
}
```

**MyDate class**

```
package lab3;

public class MyDate {

    public int day, month, year;

    public MyDate() {
        day = 1;
        month = 1;
        year = 1970;
    }
    
    public MyDate(int day, int month, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }
    
    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }   
    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }   
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }       
    public String toString() {
        return getDay() + "/" + getMonth() + "/" + getYear();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you ask about homework, at least show you put some work into it. I don't know what salary and office methods and fields have to do with this problem. Always try to post the shortest snippets which can replicate your problem, users do not need the filler code which has 0 impact on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a `MyDate` attribut in the `Employee` class, you don't need `day/month/year`, but rather instanciate a `MyDate` inside the `Employee` constructor

```
public Employee(String name) {
    super(name);
    this.office = "No office";
    this.salary = 1200.00;
    this.dateHired = new MyDate();              // uses the MyDate default constructor
    // this.dateHired = new MyDate(1, 1, 1970); // does same with the other constructor
}

public Employee(String name, String address, String phoneNumber, String email,
                String office, double salary, int day, int month, int year) {
    super(name, address, phoneNumber, email);
    this.office = office;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.dateHired = new MyDate(day, month, year);
}
```

Comment: I am required to create a MyDate class with day, month and year integer variables.

Comment: @Freezanator I don't get it, that's what I wrote, do you care of `new MyDate()` ? You have a default constructor in MyDate so let's use it, as it is the SAME as `new MyDate(1, 1, 1970)`

Comment: @Freezanator required to do it certain way? You are working on a project/work, or on homework? SO is not for homework

Comment: @azro It took me a solid couple of hours to understand. For some reason I went blank looking at your code and it suddenly hit me. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Freezanator You can now think about accepting the answer (green tick on left) ;)

Answer (score 0):

@azro gave a more correct answer which is doing how you should be doing it.

But if you insist on 'sending' it to the MyDate class then maybe something like this?

```java
this.dateHired = new MyDate();
this.dateHired.setDay(this.day);
this.dateHired.setMonth(this.month);
this.dateHired.setYear(this.year);
```

I would strongly recommend going over some tutorials/materials as it looks like you might be asking/requesting things you do not actually would want to implement

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_oop.asp

Also for homework questions:
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)